# Linear functional and Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ provided with the usual inner product $<.,.>$. Let $A\in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ a invertible matrix, $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $J:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the linear functional definition of the form
$$J(x)=<Ax,x>-2<b,x>$$
i)Determine the gradient and the Hessian matrix of functional

ii)Determine the characterization of the critical points of J

iii)Consider the matrix $A$ and the vector $b$ defined by $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 &1\\2 &1\end{bmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$classify the critical points of J

I appreciate all the help you can give me because I am not able to solve exercises on functional.

Also take this opportunity to ask any reference indication that deals on the subject and that can have examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by just computing the relevant partial derivatives.

Alternatively:

Let $f_1(x) = \langle b, x \rangle = b^T x$. Since $f_1$ is linear, we have
${\partial f_1(x) \over \partial x}h = b^Th$, and so $\nabla f_1(x) = b$. Since
$b$ is a constant, we see that ${\partial^2 f_1(x) \over \partial x^2} = 0$.

Let $f_2(x) = \langle Ax , x \rangle = x^T A^T x$. Then
$f_2(x+h)-f_2(x) = x^TA^T h + h^T A^T x + h^TA^T h = x^T(A+A^T) h + h^TA^T h$.
Since $h^TA^T h \le \|A\| \|h\|^2$, we see that $f_2$ is differentiable and
${\partial f_2(x) \over \partial x}h = x^T(A+A^T)h $, and so
$\nabla f_2(x) = (A+A^T)x$.
Since ${\partial f_2 \over \partial x}$ is linear, we have
${\partial^2 f_2(x) \over \partial x^2}h = (A+A^T)h$, and so
${\partial^2 f_2(x) \over \partial x^2} = A+A^T$.

We have $f = f_2-2 f_1$, so we can combine the gradients and Hessians as
appropriate.

Comment: You know some references that treat about this topic?

Comment: I'm not sure, I imagine any multivariable calculus text deals with partial derivatives. I found some related material in on old text I have; Marsden's "Elementary Classical Analysis".